# How do I validate localhost certificate to run ASP.NET Web App in my browser?

Tags: https, ssl-certificate, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

ASP.NET Web API in VS is unable to run in my browser due to NET::ERR_CERT_INVALID error (Your connection isn't private)

Before I ran my application, VS promted me to download the localhost certificate. When opening my certificate manager (certmgr) I see that there is a localhost certificate in my Personal folder as well as in my Trusted Root Certificate Authorities folder. However, I am still getting the same error when trying to run the application.

Comment: does thi document help:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio%2Clinux-ubuntu#trust-the-aspnet-core-https-development-certificate-on-windows-and-macos

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems that google chrome and microsoft edge may have an issue when running the wep api's via VS . I suggest installing firefox and then changing your browser to firefox in order to run your web api. When running it for the first time it may show an error but simply select advance and it should work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).